# PHP: How to explode() string of Chinese Characters

Tags: php

Hello I have this string

```
$chineseString = "号码：91"
```

What I want to do is to explode() it and get a result like this:

```
array:2[
 [0] => "号码",
 [1] => "91"
]
```

Comment: `preg_split('/: /', $chineseString)` ?

Comment: So what is your desired result??

Comment: @radmen Tried that already, and it returns an array like this 

`array:1 [
  0 => "号码：91 "
]`

Comment: use `explode(":", $chineseString)`

Comment: @markpenaranda quite possible that you need to use string functions with multibyte support (like [mb_split](https://secure.php.net/mb_split))

Comment: @radmen thanks i'll give it a try. I noticed that my semicolon is a special string thats why its not working "："

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason explode() didn't work for you is that your chineseString variable contains what is called in unicode a FULLWIDTH COLON (U+FF1A) and you are trying to split by a different character, a COLON (U+003A). So, if you use the correct character it will work.

```
$chineseString = "号码：91";
print_r(explode("：", $chineseString ));
```

Outputs: `Array([0] => 号码, [1] => 91)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this http://codepad.org/yYO3nljF

```
 <?php

    $chineseString = "号码:91";
    $d = explode(":",$chineseString );
    var_dump($d);

    ?>
```

**output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "号码"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "91"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
$chineseString = "号码:91";
print_r(preg_split('/:/', $chineseString));
```

Results in: `Array ( [0] => 号码 [1] => 91 )`